# Dictionary additional function implementations

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash-map

I've written a utility class `BetterDict` to help me on some of my other projects. I've implemented the `&`, `+`, and `-` operators. It extends from the base class `dict` so I can use all the builtin functions without having to rewrite them all. I would like some feedback on my implementation, best practices, more pythonic way of doing this, etc.

```
from typing import NewType
BetterDict = NewType('BetterDict', object)

class BetterDict(dict):
    
    def __and__(self, other: BetterDict) -> BetterDict:
        """
        Returns a dictionary containing only the keys that are
        present in both dicts.
        """
        result = BetterDict()
        for (sk, _), (ok, ov) in zip(self.items(), other.items()):
            if sk == ok:
                result[sk] = ov
        return result
    
    def __add__(self, other: BetterDict) -> BetterDict:
        """
        Combines two dictionaries, replacing same keys with "other" values.
        """
        result = BetterDict()
        for k, v in self.items():
            result[k] = v
        for k, v in other.items():
            result[k] = v
        return result
    
    def __sub__(self, other: BetterDict) -> BetterDict:
        """
        Returns a dictionary containing only the keys that are not
        present in both dicts.
        """
        result = BetterDict()
        keys = list(set(self.keys()).symmetric_difference(other.keys()))
        for key in keys:
            if key in self.keys():
                result[key] = self[key]
            if key in other.keys():
                result[key] = other[key]
        return result
```

Example Code

```
from better_dict import BetterDict

a = BetterDict({'a': 1})
b = BetterDict({'a': 3, 'b': 2})

print(a & b)
print(a + b)
print(a - b)
```

Comment: Your implementation of `__and__()` does not work as claimed. For example, `print(BetterDict({'z': 3, 'a': 2, 'b': 1}) & BetterDict({'a': 3, 'b': 2}))` produces an empty dict. You need to figure out which keys exist in both dicts, not simply assume that items from each dict are stored in the same order (chances are, they are not).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @FMc already commented, your method `__add__()` assumes that both dicts have the same keys at the same positions, which is a very bold assumption.

Furthermore, the documentation of `__add__()` does not indicate, that *values* of `other` will override values of `self`, which may be surprising to the user (and users generally don't like to be surprised).

Some further nitpicks:

- You restrict `other` to `BetterDict`, though it would also work with a plain old `dict`.
- I don't like `for (sk, _), (ok, ov) in zip(self.items(), other.items()):` since you throw away the value of the first item anyway. It should read `for sk, (ok, ov) in zip(self.keys(), other.items()):` imho. But since this assumes, that both dicts have the same keys in the same places, this should be rewritten entirely anyways.
- Instead of the `NewType` you should use `typing.Self` when referring to `BetterDict` within its methods.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting class.

What motivated it?
You might come up with some more descriptive name than `BetterDict`,
perhaps a name drawn from the business domain that motivated it.

---

## comprehensions

The first two methods, {`__and__`, `__or__`},
might become just "return some dict comprehension".

---

## C-language intersection

The builtin `set` operators are implemented
in C rather than python bytecode.
I wonder if, at least for some workloads,
`__and__` would go quicker if we were to use
the intersection of these sets:
`self.keys() & other.keys()`

---

## dict addition

This is idiomatically a one-liner:

```
        return { **self, **other }
```

We have defined certain semantics, but they are not the ones
the word "addition" would have called to mind.
For example, adding a pair of `Counter` objects won't sum the counts.
Adding a pair of `id_to_list` dicts won't yield .values() with longer lists.

Well now, this is funny.
I was about to suggest to you that dict `|` union seems the
more natural description of the semantics this offers,
similar to set union.
So I did a little digging around, and learned that
[pep-584](https://peps.python.org/pep-0584)
implemented `d1 | d2` a few years back, in cPython 3.9.
Notice that it doesn't commute: `(d1 | d2) != (d2 | d1)`

---

## dict subtraction

I guess I'm gonna have to quibble about *this*
notation, too.

You're explicitly relying on `.symmetric_difference()`,
which is very nice, I'm sure it's fast,
it works fine for a pair of sets `s1 ^ s2`.

The natural notation for your dictionary operation
would be `d1 ^ d2`.
I feel the current notation is misleading,
for same reason as above with addition.

I wonder if a pair of
[filter()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter)
operations would go quicker than the current code,
at least for some workloads.

---

## unit tests

It wouldn't hurt to throw in an automated
[test suite](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase).
The three `print`'s don't tell the Gentle Reader
what the expected output is, and they won't show
a Red bar if a maintenance engineer introduces a regression.

Example workloads and benchmark timings wouldn't hurt, either.

---

I don't agree with the notation choices, but
this codebase *does* achieve its original design goals.

I would be willing to delegate or accept maintenance tasks on it.